# How to give blank data for Oboe library to play as sound?

Tags: android, c++, audio, oboe

Sometimes I want my audio output in Oboe to play nothing, but I dont want it to stop, I just want it to be silent while no data arrives. I tried:

```
static void writeBlankData(float* pointer, int numFrames) {
    std::fill_n(pointer, numFrames, 0);
}
oboe::DataCallbackResult PlayRecordingCallback::onAudioReady(
        oboe::AudioStream *audioStream,
        void *audioData,
        int numFrames) {
    float *floatData = (float *) audioData;
    writeBlankData(floatData, numFrames);
    return oboe::DataCallbackResult::Continue;
}
```

but I hear a buzzing on the audio output instead of silence. Shouldn't an array of `0`s be silence? I tried `-1.0f` also which gives a different buzzing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the stream is in stereo so has 2 samples per frame. Your current code assumes a mono stream.

Try changing:

```
writeBlankData(floatData, numFrames);
```

To:

```
writeBlankData(floatData, numFrames * audioStream->getChannelCount());
```

Comment: Hello Don, does writing blank data cause any overheads? Like battery consumption etc In my app i only want to play the audio when user touches a button, to get the minimal latency should I keep the stream open and only write non blank data when user presses the button?

Comment: There will be some extra power consumption associated with keeping a stream open. I don't have any figures on how much extra power is used but I don't imagine it to be significant when compared to keeping the screen on.